# paperclip + gravatar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, gravatar

I've found this tutorial (http://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/02/15/graceful-degredation-using-gravatar-as-a-fallback-avatar-with-paperclip/) about implementing gravatar as default image to the paperclip-enabled model, but on implementing i see message "undefined method `match' for [:format, :png]:Array". Whats wrong in this article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the code to make it easier for you to understand and debug.

```
Paperclip.interpolates(:gravatar_url) do |attachment, style|
  size = nil
  # style should be :tiny, :small, or :regular
  # size_data is assumed to be "16x16#", "20x20#", or "25x25#", i.e., a string
  size_data = attachment.styles[style][:geometry]
  if size_data
    # get the width of the attachment in pixels
    if thumb_size = size_data.match(/\d+/).to_a.first
      size = thumb_size.to_i
    end
  end
  # obtain the url from the model
  # replace nil with "identicon", "monsterid", or "wavatar" as desired
  # personally I would reorder the parameters so that size is first
  # and default is second
  attachment.instance.gravatar_url(nil, size)
end
```

Comment: what about styles like :thumb => ['75x75#', :png] ??

Comment: also - i've updated this code with
    Paperclip.interpolates :gravatar_url  do |attachment, style|

and

    attachment.instance.gravatar_url("", size)

Comment: Right... that's why I added all those comments.  `['75x75#', :png]` will cause an error because the article assumes `size_data` is a string.  If it's not, then you need to update the code to do: `size_data = size_data.first if size_data.kind_of?(Array)`  Or something similar.

Comment: solved by "if thumb_size = size_data.to_s.match(/\d+/).to_a.first"

Comment: No offense, but that's... a really bad solution.

Answer (score 2):

Note I got the following error when attempting this solution:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for #<Hash:0xb6476178>
    from /home/bob/dev/Firehoze/app/models/user.rb:114:in `gravatar_url'
```

I solved it by replacing the line:

```
size_data = attachment.styles[style].first
```

with

```
size_data = attachment.styles[style][:geometry]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Paperclip.interpolates :gravatar_url do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.gravatar_url(attachment.styles[style][:geometry].split('x').first)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to have trouble, you could try the [Avatar](http://github.com/gcnovus/avatar) gem, which supports a chain of different Avatar methods, including both Paperclip and Gravatar.

NB: this is a bit of a shameless plug, since I wrote the thing.

Comment: yeah, i've seen. But there are not enought docs to understand how to use your gem :(